# Postback event not firing in ASP.NET Master Page from POST

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I have an ASP.NET Web Forms project underway, and I have built a Master Page which contains a footer.  In that footer is a small piece of code to let users subscribe to our email list.  That code is:

```
                    <aside class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-3">
                        <h6 class="footer-title">Newsletter</h6>
                        <p>Receive the latest updates about our services.</p>
                        <form id="frmEmail" name="frmEmail" method="post" class="mb-3 needs-validation" novalidate>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input class="form-control" name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email" required>
                                <button class="btn btn-light" type="submit" id="btnJoin" name="btnJoin">Join</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </aside>
```

The following Javascript is used to handle the form submission:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#frmEmail").submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var forms = document.getElementsByName('frmEmail');
                var validation = Array.prototype.map.call(forms, function (form) {
                    form.classList.add('was-validated');
                    return form.checkValidity();
                });

                if (!validation.every(el => el)) {
                    return false;
                }
                setDisabled();
                alert('got here');
                forms.submit();
            });
        })

        function setDisabled() {
            $('#btnJoin').prop('disabled', true).html('<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span> Wait...');
        }
    </script>
```

What I am TRYING to do is process the post in the master page code-behind, like so:

```
        protected void Page_Load ( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
            if ( Page.IsPostBack ) {
                var email=HttpContext.Current.Request["email"];
                if ( email != null ) { }
            }
        }
```

The problem is, even though the Javascript seems to process correctly (the alert box I added pops up), the code-behind of the master page is never reached.  Can anyone help on this?

Comment: any particular reason you not using a plain jane asp.net button? And you could add a runat="server" to that button. And why are you starting a new "form" tag - I would not do that at all. Just use a "div" or whatever, but a form tag means you have 2 form tags in that markup, and that's going to be a bit messy to deal with.

Comment: I don't have any other form tags in that page.  I don't want to use a server-side form here, because you can only have one server-side form in a page, and this is a master page, so it would prevent me from using a server-side form in any content page.

Comment: the master page by default WILL MOST certainly have a form for the base layout of that master page (and it can't work otherwise). You are 100% free to drop in that markup to the master page, but NOT with a whole new extra form tag beyond the default one that existed in the first place.  so, yes, I am saying that your markup will be placed in the existing master page form tag area. It is possible you now not talking about content in the master page, and your markup was in fact inside of the child page???  Regardless, yes, your master page should and will have an existing form tag(s).

Comment: Child pages place their markup inside of the content area - and don't require, and should not have a form tag in such child pages.  Such a setup is not standard (no form in master page). If you do this, then you can't have buttons in the master page and that REALLY limits the functions available in the master page. If you were migration existing forms to use a master page, then you simple remove the form tag in the child page, and everything would work and be fine without extra efforts. And when you create (add) any new web page, you of course choose create new with master page.

Comment: Converting it to an asp.net button throws the error "Control 'btnJoin' of type 'Button' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server".  So that didn't work.

Comment: Having stated all of the above? Use type="button" and not submit for the button - that usually works, but you have much greater issue(s) here - and that is the master page without a form.

Comment: Correct about the button not allowed. You are ONLY allowed ONE form tag on a given page. If you introduce into master page a form tag, now all your child pages that have a form tag will break and not work! That's why I stated the correct design pattern the form tag is in the master page.All child pages created will automatic by default thus not have that form tag in those pages. VS will manage this assuming that you don't try and introduce form tags to the child pages. We are dealing with 2 issues here. You can probably get code to work, but you should fix the overall design flaw first.